# Android pass object from App Fragment to module fragment

Tags: android, kotlin, dependency-injection

I have an android app (`main`) that creates an object -- in a singleton manner and is used throughout the application. The class is called `NetworkFrame` which is a common module in the project.

The `main` app has an activity that contains a fragment which exists in another module in the project (`viewer`). The `viewer` module is imported into the main app using Gradle. I need to pass the `NetworkFrame` object to the `viewer` fragment.

Both the module and the app both have `NetworkFrame` as a dependency.

The object is too detailed to use serializable or Parcel. I have looked into dependency injection, but I'm not sure if that's the correct use of it.

```
class MainApplication : Application() {
    companion object {
        var networkFrame: NetworkFrame? = null
    }
}
```

```
class MainFragment : Fragment() {

...
        if (MainApplication.networkFrame == null) {
            MainApplication.networkFrame = networkFrame
        }
        viewModel.networkFrame = MainApplication.networkFrame
...


}
```

Above shows the creation of the object in the main application. I need to pass this object to the `viewer` fragment's `networkFrame` object.

```
class ViewerModel : ViewModel() {
    var networkFrame: NetworkFrame? = null
}
```

What's the best way to get this object to the `viewer` fragment?

Answer (score 0):

I think that you require an instance of `NetworkFrame` then I recommend to you create an interface that provides to you the instance

```
interface HasNetworkFrame {
  fun getNetworkFrame(): NetworkFrame
}
```

This interface should be implemented on the application, something like this

```
class OneApplication : Application(), HasNetworkFrame{
   fun getNetworkFrame(): NetworkFrame {
     // return your object
   }
}
```

And in your fragment can access via something like this

```
val frame = (requireContext().applicationContext as? HasNetworkFrame)?.getNetworkFrame()
```

However i think that this is not a good approach, take a look into solid principles and put focus on

> Dependency Inversion Principle

Comment: Unfortunately the module doesn't have access to the applicationContext of the MainApplication